# React native reference error Can't find variable :style

Tags: react-native

I implemented a react-native log in page and i added some styles for it. But then i run it on my emiulator, It gives me this reference error can't find variable: style

This is my login.js code --

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { Alert, Button,Text, TextInput, View,TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
// import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
        email: '', 
        password: '', 
        errorMassage:null
        
      }
  
  render() {

      return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={style.greeting}>{"Helloo.."}</Text>

            <View style={styles.errorMassage}>
                <Text>Error</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.form}>
                  <View>
                        <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>Email Address</Text>
                        <TextInput style={styles.input} ></TextInput>

                  </View>


                  <View>
                        <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>Password</Text>
                        <TextInput style={styles.input} securityTextEntry autoCapitalize ="none" ></TextInput>

                  </View>
            </View>

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={{color:"#FFF",fontWeight:"500"}}>Sign in</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity style={{alignSelf:"center",marginTop:32}}>
                <Text style={{color:"#414959",fontSize:13}}>New To EduApp?<Text style={{color:"#E9446A",fontWeight:"500"}}></Text>

                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>



        </View>
      );
    
  }
 }


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },

  greeting: {
    marginTop:32,
    fontSize:18,
    fontWeight:"400",
    textAlign:"center"
  },

  errorMassage:{
    alignItems:"center"  

  },
  form:{
    marginBottom:48,
    marginHorizontal:30
  },
  input:{
    borderBottomColor:"#8A8F9E",
    borderBottomWidth:StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    fontSize:15,
    color:"#161F3D"
  },
  inputTitle: {
    color:"#8A8F9E",
    fontSize:10,
    textTransform:"uppercase"

  },
  button:{
    marginHorizontal:30,
    backgroundColor:"#E9446A",
    borderRadius:4,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  }
});
```

And this is the error I got in my emulator.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: typo here: `<Text style={style.greeting}>{"Helloo.."}</Text>`

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because of a typo in your code. It is located on line 17 of the code you supplied. style.greetings should be styles.greeting.

**Replace**

```
<Text style={style.greeting}>{"Helloo.."}</Text>
```

**with**

```
<Text style={styles.greeting}>{"Helloo.."}</Text>
```

One way to decrease these kinds of mistakes is to use a code editor that supports the eslint extension which amongs many things underline missing variables. One that I have had good experiences with is Visual Studio Code.